# PHP: Get string as streamoutput always extra letters

Tags: php, http-headers

What I try to do:

- Generating XML (Sepa-XML) - Working!
- Saving it to db - Working! (I just write the whole content as BLOB)
- Let the user download the File - NOT Working like I want

My Code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ID,XML FROM table WHERE ID = ?';
//Connect here
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->bind_param('i', $_GET['download_xml']);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($ID, $file);
    $result->fetch();
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test_".$ID.".xml");       
    print($file);
```

It gives me the file, but XML-Checker tells me that there are characters in front of the `<xml`. If I open the file in notepad no characters are in front of the `<xml`.

When I save the data with `file_put_contents()` it is working fine and I'm getting a well formatted XML-File.

Comment: I'm taking a really wild guess here and odds are I may be wrong. It could be [zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) or [byte mark order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) related stuff. Even if I'm right, I have no idea how to fix it. I'm hoping somebody smarter than me can help you out on that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have extra charaters before the opening php tag.

This could led to problems when downloading a file as there is a "space" in front of the opening tag.

```
 <?php ....
```

This looks equal but will work as there is no char in front of the tag.

```
<?php ...
```

The webserver sends those extra chars out before the php output, which will corrupt the file.

Comment: Thanks. The Problem was, that the file was a encoded as UTF-8 with BOM. Changing it to UTF-8 without BOM did it.

Comment: Great you could solve the problem on your own. Feel free to answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that the file was a encoded as UTF-8 with BOM. Changing it to **UTF-8 without BOM** did it.